# After DDL statement, all the data inserted, updated or deleted is committed?

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose if I executed three Insert Statement  and After that I fired a DDL statement, so data presented in three insert statement is committed in Oracle

Comment: Do you mean : insert the data before creating the table? This won't work.

Comment: Yes in Mysql always queries are Committed, so no rollback is possible . You need to change variable setting for default setting. use `Show variables;  to see setting

Comment: Check `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'autocommit'`

Comment: This is clearly documented in the chapter named "Transactions" in the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/transact.htm#CNCPT88953

Comment: thanks a-horse-with-no-name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle,  DDL statements include an implicit COMMIT.

So, yes, the INSERT statements would be committed when you ran the DDL.